# Select first and last row for each group and take the column value difference in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the following table structure

| SYMBOL | DATE | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 2021-02-21 | 10 |
| TSLA | 2021-02-21 | 800 |
| AMZN | 2021-02-21 | 90 |
| AAPL | 2021-02-20 | 17 |
| TSLA | 2021-02-20 | 900 |
| AMZN | 2021-02-20 | 105 |
| AAPL | 2021-02-19 | 5 |
| TSLA | 2021-02-19 | 960 |
| AMZN | 2021-02-19 | 80 |
| .... | .... | .... |

**Question:** Now, for a given date range `date >= '2021-02-19' and date <= '2021-02-21'`  I wish to find the price difference for that date range. That is, the following is my desired output after performing a query,

| SYMBOL | PRICE_CHANGE |
| --- | --- |
| AAPL | 5 |
| TSLA | -160 |
| AMZN | 10 |
| .... | .... |

**My Attempt**:

```
(SELECT symbol, "date"
FROM public.ticks 
where "date" >= '2021-02-19 11:30:00' and  "date" <= '2021-02-19 12:30:00'
order by "date" desc) t group by t.symbol;
```

I'm unable to figure out how to go about with a group by and selecting the first and last row of the group and subtracting the price.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this first - last or min vs max? Which MySQL version? You will need to self JOIN or window functions to get the two values.

Comment: @danblack it's the price difference of the lowest date and the highest date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a MySQL-8.0/ MariaDB-10.2+ window function:

```
SELECT symbol,
       LAST - FIRST AS price_change
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT symbol,
                   first_value(price) OVER w AS FIRST,
                   last_value(price) OVER w AS LAST
   FROM ticks WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY symbol
                           ORDER BY date
                           ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
   ) AS p
```

ref: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea109794af16a2c54718ea12dc2181ef)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of at least a couple of ideas.

First idea:

```
SELECT symbol, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(prices,',',1)-SUBSTRING_INDEX(prices,',',-1) AS price_change
FROM
    (SELECT symbol, GROUP_CONCAT(price ORDER BY `date` DESC) prices
      FROM ticks 
      WHERE `date` >= '2021-02-19' AND `date` <= '2021-02-21'
 GROUP BY symbol) a;
```

Second idea:

```
SELECT a.symbol, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.`date`=max_date THEN price END) AS u,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.`date`=min_date THEN price END) AS m,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.`date`=max_date THEN price END)-SUM(CASE WHEN a.`date`=min_date THEN price END) AS price_change
FROM ticks a 
JOIN 
   (SELECT symbol, MIN(`date`) AS min_date, MAX(`date`) AS max_date
      FROM ticks WHERE `date` >= '2021-02-19' AND `date` <= '2021-02-21'
 GROUP BY symbol) b
 ON a.symbol=b.symbol
 GROUP BY a.symbol;
```

Fiddle demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0168329820ddbacfa5d0356a6f3ba2ea

Answer (score 1):

We can use temporary tables to calculate the result. temporary tables are supported in all modern MySQL Server version. They last only during the current connection. See a [description of temporary tables](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-temporary-table/) for more information.

See following SQL:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE min_date_tbl (
    `symbol` varchar(4),
    `min_date` datetime    
);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE max_date_tbl (
    `symbol` varchar(4),
    `max_date` datetime    
);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE min_price_tbl (
    `symbol` varchar(4),
    `min_price` int    
);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE max_price_tbl (
    `symbol` varchar(4),
    `max_price` int    
);

INSERT INTO min_date_tbl (SELECT symbol, MIN(date) as min_date from ticks where date >= '2021-02-19' and date <= '2021-02-21' group by symbol);

INSERT INTO max_date_tbl (SELECT symbol, MAX(date) as max_date from ticks where date >= '2021-02-19' and date <= '2021-02-21' group by symbol);

INSERT INTO min_price_tbl (SELECT t1.symbol, t1.price as min_price FROM ticks t1, min_date_tbl t2 WHERE t1.symbol=t2.symbol AND t1.date=t2.min_date);

INSERT INTO max_price_tbl (SELECT t1.symbol, t1.price as max_price FROM ticks t1, max_date_tbl t2 WHERE t1.symbol=t2.symbol AND t1.date=t2.max_date);


SELECT t1.symbol as SYMBOL, (t2.max_price - t1.min_price) as PRICE_CHANGE FROM min_price_tbl t1, max_price_tbl t2 WHERE t1.symbol=t2.symbol
```

I created and tested this [SQL code on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7etiG1y1PEQ8k1hLHKvHC3/0). It produced the required results.